# How to pass in info associated with which button was pressed in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have created a model object called Store and passed it to a django template and called it in a for loop within a POST form as the following:

```html
<form action="/order_page/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" name="student_id" >
            
    <br/><br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        {% for store in stores %}
            <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{{store.id}}">
            <input type="submit" value="{{store.store_name}}{{store.id}}" class="button store-button" type="button">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```

It works fine, shows all the buttons with each store name and id on clicking the button it submits the form and takes me to next template where I have captured the POST store id  and student id and passed them to next page template. But the problem is that the store shown is always the last added store, no matter which button I press in the first page of the POST form, but the buttons show the different stores and their ids perfectly, I can't understand why this is happening as not even an error is shown.

Comment: The usual way to do this in Django would do use a separate URL for the detailed score page and then linking each button to it. Can you share your code from views and urls?

Comment: @Jain The usual way to do this would be using ajax

Comment: def home(request):
    stores = Store.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'tray/home.html', {'stores':stores})

def order_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student_id = request.POST['student_id']
        store_id = request.POST['store_id']
        student = Student.objects.get(id = student_id)
        store = Store.objects.get(id = store_id)
    return render (request, 'tray/order_

Answer (score 0):

delete the hidden input
and change submit input to button:

```html
<button type="submit" name="store_id" value="{{store.id}}" class="button store-button">{{store.store_name}}{{store.id}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, by selecting the store_name attribute from the store instead of it's id and it works, not exactly sure why the id doesn't work the same way though